# ORA-06550 Why I can't create index inside the if-else in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I not family with PL/SQL. Can anyone explain why I can't do the following?

```
BEGIN
  IF TRUE THEN
    CREATE INDEX TestIndex ON SomeTable (SomeColumn);
  END IF;
END;
```

I would get the following error:

Error report:
ORA-06550: line 3, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:
   begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with 
     <<
   close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

The only way I can by pass this error is do dynamic sql:

```
BEGIN
  IF TRUE THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX TestIndex ON SomeTable (SomeColumn)';
  END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle doesn't allow DDL in a PL/SQL block as static SQL so you've identified the only workaround (well, technically, you could use DBMS_SQL rather than EXECUTE IMMEDIATE but you'd still be dealing with dynamic SQL).

I don't know that there is any technical reason that they couldn't allow DDL in static SQL.  But since 99% of the time you shouldn't be doing DDL in a stored procedure-- creating objects is something that would almost exclusively be done when you're doing a deployment rather than at runtime-- forcing people to use dynamic SQL makes developers pause to consider whether they're really in that 1% of cases where such a thing makes sense.

Comment: I am actually working on a deployment and database upgrade scripts. Most of the personal who use the scripts don't have DBA experience, and I am trying to make the scripts robust so that it can be repeatable without error. So, I need to perform if else logic to handles different scenario.